# Loading multiple language files in CodeIgniter

Tags: file, codeigniter, localization

Can I load multiple language files for the same view in CodeIgniter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ah...

Well it was pretty simple. I just loaded the two files with `$this->lang->load()`.

```
$this->lang->load("lang_file1");
$this->lang->load("lang_file2");
```

Then after the view is loaded, I can use strings from the both files. But I'm not sure of the consequences of the same string being in different lang files.

I also saw that you can even load multiple views in CodeIgniter. Just have to load them consecutively and CodeIgniter will merge them into one view.

Comment: You can also use `$this->lang->load( array('file1', 'file2') );`

Answer (score 0):

This example loads one class from the system library and one from application library.

```
$this->load->library(array( 'form_validation','form_validate_supplement'));
```

Answer (score 0):

From the codeigniter documentation,

```
$this->lang->load(array('menu', 'text'), 'french');
```

[Codeigniter documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/language.html)