# Dynamically set language with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to set the default application language as my visitor countries language. I have an API to get the IP prefix idiom and based in this information, I want to set the language.

What is the best way to do this? I want to make a cookie to store the language identifier, but where do I have to set this?

Thanks.

Comment: You can read browser's language using Javascript and using Ajax to call your own function to set the language (without using cookies).

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to set based on IP. They may be using a proxy, and also what if they are not speaking the native language? Also, there may be multiple common languages in a country. e.g. Canada. What language do you pick then?

Comment: I agree with @conor and I would use the browser's language using `$_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"]`. Not 100% reliable but better than the ip address.

Comment: Howdy, Fellas. Thank you for the tips. I'll use HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE... But how can I apply this? Where can I the HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE for all the system?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you seen [CodeIgniter's Language library](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/language.html)?

**The Language Class provides functions to retrieve language files and lines of text for purposes of internationalization.**

**In your CodeIgniter system folder you'll find one called language containing sets of language files. You can create your own language files as needed in order to display error and other messages in other languages.**

**Language files are typically stored in your system/language directory. Alternately you can create a folder called language inside your application folder and store them there. CodeIgniter will look first in your application/language directory. If the directory does not exist or the specified language is not located there CI will instead look in your global system/language folder.**

In your case...

- you need to create a `polish_lang.php` and `english_lang.php` inside application/language/polish
- then create your keys inside that file (e.g. `$lang['hello'] = "Witaj"`;
- then load it in your controller like `$this->lang->load('polish_lang', 'polish');`
- then fetch the line like `$this->lang->line('hello');` Just store the return value of this function in a variable so you can use it in your view.

Repeat the steps for the english language and all other languages you need.

Comment: I already did this. I can read the languages keys in the View/Controller. The problem is: how to do this dynamically?

Comment: and see also :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018755/loading-multiple-language-files-in-codeigniter

Comment: Hello, Abid. Thank you for the help! But if I do not load a specific controller what have the language setter? I mean, I'll get/set the defualt language in the Index Controller, but if I load the page from a "products" controller?

Comment: See above the URL i think it very use full to you.