# How to override $config['language'] in config.php

Tags: php, codeigniter

In config.php the default language is set to "english". But I want to change the default language through controller so that I can switch languages later based on session.How can I do that?
I tried the below code. But still the language is displayed in english

```
public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();

            $this->config->set_item('language', 'japanese' );
        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically set language with CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11937582/dynamically-set-language-with-codeigniter)

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35997583/codeigniter-change-language-form-validation-lang